# how can I insert a link on login page

Tags: plugin-development, login

I want to insert a link in login page in between the Login button and the password field, Is it possible ? if possible which action i need to hook ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a hook called `login_form` that is [placed where you need it](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-login.php#L703).

```
add_action(
  'login_form',
  function() {
    echo 'howdy ho!';
  }
);
```